# Prove that $a^m + (a+1)^n \equiv 1 + a(1 + (-1)^{m-1})\pmod {a(a+1)}$

Tags: congruence-relations

This question is for all $a,m$ and $n$ $\in \mathbb{N}$

I'm really stuck on this question, I tried splitting the modulus and doing the congruence one at a time but can't find a way to put it back using CRT.

Because

> $(a+1)^n \equiv 0\pmod {a+1}$ and  $a^m \equiv 0\pmod a$

Also, I found out by trying different integers that

> $(a+1)^n \equiv 1\pmod a$

Will this be useful for proving the question?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\rm\ LHS-RHS\equiv 0\,$ mod $a$ and mod $a\!+\!1$ so it is divisible by $\,a\,$ and $\,a\!+\!1\,$ thus also by their lcm = product = $\,a(a\!+\!1)\,$ since they are coprime. Note that mod $\ a\!+\!1\!:\ a\!+\!1\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\, a\equiv -1.$

---

Or, using CRT verify that both sides are solutions of $\, x\equiv 1\pmod{a},\ x\equiv (-1)^m\pmod{a\!+\!1}\,$ hence, by CRT *uniqueness*, they are congruent $\!\pmod{a(a+1)}\,$

---

[Quite frequently,](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+uniqueness+powerful+tools+equalities)  *uniqueness theorems* provide powerful tools for **proving equalities.**

Comment: For the second solution, how did you get the solutions $ x\equiv 1\pmod{a},\ x\equiv (-1)^m\pmod{a\!+\!1}\ $ ? And how does it lead to congruence by CRT? I thought you can only merge the (mod a(a+1)) if both solutions are common.

Comment: @jasonderulo  $\ x_1 :=  a^m + (a+1)^n\equiv (-1)^m + 0^n\pmod{a+1}.\,$ Similarly $\,x_1\equiv 1\pmod a.\,$ Thus $\,x_1\,$ is a solution of said system of congruences. Similarly, $\,x_2 := 1+a(1+(-1)^{m-1})\,$ is a solution of the system. Thus $\,x_1 \equiv x_2\pmod{a(a+1)}\,$ by CRT uniqueness.